# Open Workbook command using variables as file name

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I am building some code to open excel files in certain directory folders. I have some variables captured elsewhere and need to essentially concatenate the strings that make up the file name in the correct command line sytax.

The problem is with  this code compilation, I need some help with  this command code to launch the workbook Open;

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=(toFolder & fYear & fA & fPeriod & JEres) _
```

The line of command code is within this sub, all of the variables are defining correctly, I am failing to get the right code structure to launch the file.

The file is txt so the large block of code below the open command is text to columns which is working fine. Everything works independently except the Workbooks.OpenText command.

Any  suggestions please?

Cheers!

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim fYear As String
Dim fPeriod As String
Const toFolder As String = "C:\Users\jblogs\Documents\VBA\TFAR"
Const fA As String = "\FA\"
Const JEres As String = "\Constant_File_Name.txt"

x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
fYear = Range("A" & x).Value
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B"))
fPeriod = Range("B" & y).Value

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=(toFolder & fYear & fA & fPeriod & JEres) _
    , Origin:=xlMSDOS, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
    , Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:="^", FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1 _
    ), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array _
    (20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(26, 1), _
    Array(27, 1), Array(28, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1), Array(32, 1), Array( _
    33, 1), Array(34, 1), Array(35, 1), Array(36, 1), Array(37, 1), Array(38, 1), Array(39, 1), _
    Array(40, 1), Array(41, 1), Array(42, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True`
```

Comment: What happens when you `debug.print` your variables and their concatenation? Do you get what you expect?

Comment: Sorry only 2 months new to VBA how do I use Debug.Print? I tried quickly and was not getting any results

Answer (score 0):

Without having the exact spreadsheet in front of me, it's impossible to be certain as I can't reproduce your problem exactly, but it's probably something to do with a type conversion when you concatenate the numbers for fYear and fPeriod into the file name.  It could be a leading or trailing space inserted into the file name.

While the exact circumstances that compel me to do this are lost in the swirling mists of time, I always do a text conversion from integer to string when building a string with a file name in either an Excel formula or in VBA.

So I'd try this:

```
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
fYear = Range("A" & Format(x, "0").Value
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B"))
fPeriod = Range("B" & Format(y, "0").Value
```

That's assuming that x and y are integers.

Comment: Thanks you got me checking in  the right space, believe there was a missing backslash, i will try this later :)

Comment: Thanks, got this working now, as mentioned it was a missing backslash which should have been in this const code at the end.....


    Const toFolder As String = "C:\Users\jblogs\Documents\VBA\TFAR"